# Read all vector elements as one integer in C++

Tags: c++, vector, deque

I have this deque and this vector:

```
std::deque<uint8_t> Time(3);
std::vector<uint8_t> deque_buffer(3);
```

I do some `push_backs`:

```
Time.push_back(1);
Time.push_back(2);
Time.push_back(3);
```

I copy the data to the `vector`

```
for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
{
    deque_buffer.at(i) = Time.at(i);
}
```

I want to read all the vector data and store it into an `int`. Meaning I want `0x010203` to be interpreted as `66051`. How do I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what you can do: (sample code on how to "merge" vector elements).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector> 
using namespace std;

int main()
{


    vector<unsigned char> vec = {1,2,3};
    int res = 0;

    for (const auto &val:vec)
    {
        res = (res << 8 ) | val;
    }

    printf ("0x%x\n",res);
    printf ("%d\n",res);
    return 0;
}
```